# Issue with Django blog tutorial on youtube, class view and GET method not clear

Tags: python, django, listview, get, blogs

Was following a youtube tut regarding a django blog but ran into an issue.
Link to video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CnaB4Nb0-R8&t=607s
The tut says to use the following code in the blog app's view.py file:

```
from django.views.generic. import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Post
from django.views import View

class Blogview(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog.html'
```

When I tried to implement the code this way, I was given an error referencing something to do with GET.  Looking into it, I modified my code to look like the following:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post
from django.views import View

class Blogview(View):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog.html'
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request,'blog.html')
```

The above version of code works now for me.  I find it frustrating why I couldn't figure out why the youtube tutorial code seemed to be much simlified and worked just as expected, whereas when I tried it word for word it failed and had to include a reference to the get method.

I'll let you know I did simplify my version of the template file 'blog.html' to be something as simple as a single line of text whereas the tutorial had a template file which took all the posts stored in the database, iterated through them and listed them.  Am I wrong to assume that this should not have been the reason his version of code worked but when I wrote his code on my machine it did not, having to be modified to include get method?

Hope all is clear. any questions welcome. thanks

Comment: "*eferencing something to do with GET*", can you please share the full traceback, this makes debugging a lot easier.

Comment: Kindly share error which you encountered.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by using the attribute 'CreateView'.

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView
from .models import Post

class Blogview(CreateView): 
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog.html'
    fields = '__all__'
```

Since my template 'blog.html' simply does nothing but is static html, CreateView is apparently thew attribute required to be used in the class Blogview(CreateView).

If I were to make the template more complex and have it perform further functionality such as listing all the posts in my database, then I would need to
make the class Blogview(*ATTRIBUTE*) the correct one for this functionality, which I believe would be the ListView one.

Am I using the correct terminology by referring to these as attributes?, also, is it possible to use more than one at a time, so  for instance the following;

```
class Blogview(ListView, DetailView):
```

or would this not work?

thanks for the help.